# dictionary of dictionaries is not ordering properly

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a list of logs that show 3 items - userid, time, sign-in or sign-out

```
logs = ["12 150 sign-out","30 90 sign-in","12 10 sign-in","30 120 sign-out"]
```

I am trying to create a dictionary of jsons dictionaries

```
outlist = {}
for log in logs:
    buff = log.split()
    if buff[0] not in outlist.keys():
        outlist[buff[0]] = {}
    if buff[2] == 'sign-in':
        outlist[buff[0]].update({'sign-in':buff[1]})
    elif buff[2] == 'sign-out':
        outlist[buff[0]]['sign-out']=buff[1]
```

The outlist looks like this:

```
{'12': {'sign-out': '150', 'sign-in': '10'},
 '30': {'sign-in': '90', 'sign-out': '120'}}
```

I want it to look like below, where the sign-in is at the front. I use update method to insert at the beginning, but it is not working. Where I am going wrong?

```
{'12': {'sign-in': '10','sign-out': '150'},
 '30': {'sign-in': '90', 'sign-out': '120'}}
```

Comment: what version of python is it? Also - why you do not access dict elements by key?

Comment: Python 3.10.9 is the version. If there is a better way to write this please suggest.

Comment: any what you want to solve by keeping the order? why it matters?

Comment: Python dictionaries since 3.6? maintain insertion order. But in general hashmaps are *unordered*, that is not *usually* an important property of a hashmap. There are cases where order matters but they're rare, are you sure this is one of them?

Comment: You can create a new dict where you  add the keys in desired order and replace the previous dict with it.

Comment: If your final result is JSON text, `json.dumps()` has a `sort_keys=True` option and you don't need to worry about the in-memory order.

Answer (score 0):

As of Python version `3.7`, dictionaries are [ordered](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). This means that they would remember the order in which keys are inserted.

Note that in the `logs`, for key `12`, `sign-out` comes before `sign-in` and for key `30`, `sign-in` comes before `sign-out`.

`logs = ["12 150 sign-out","30 90 sign-in","12 10 sign-in","30 120 sign-out"]`

And since you are reading and inserting the entry in the logs in order, the final output would contain them in the same order (provided that you are on `Python>=3.7`).

Now if you want an output where each dictionary in `outlist` has all its keys sorted, you can simply [sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-python-dictionaries-by-key-or-value/) the final dictionary after generating it completely. This solution is independent if whether you are on `python>=3.7` or `python<3.7`. So, for each dictionary under `outlist`, we collected all its keys, sorted them and recreated the dictionary with keys in order.

**Solution**:

```py
# Same as your code to build `outlist`
outlist = {}
for log in logs:
    buff = log.split()
    if buff[0] not in outlist.keys():
        outlist[buff[0]] = {}
    if buff[2] == 'sign-in':
        outlist[buff[0]].update({'sign-in':buff[1]})
    elif buff[2] == 'sign-out':
        outlist[buff[0]]['sign-out']=buff[1]

print(outlist)
>> {'12': {'sign-out': '150', 'sign-in': '10'},
 '30': {'sign-in': '90', 'sign-out': '120'}}

for key in outlist:
    inner_keys = list(outlist[key].keys())
    inner_keys.sort()
    outlist[key] = {inner_key: outlist[key][inner_key] for inner_key in inner_keys}

print(outlist)
{'12': {'sign-in': '10', 'sign-out': '150'},
 '30': {'sign-in': '90', 'sign-out': '120'}}
```

**Edit**

Based on the comment regarding time complexity and doing it in one pass.

Time complexity would be `O(2N*log(k))` where `k` is the number of keys in each dictionary under `outlist`. However if there are only two keys possible, i.e. `sign-in` and `sign-out`, `k` becomes constant and time complexity would be `O(2N)`.

To do it in one pass, assuming that only two keys viz. `sign-in` and `sign-out` are possible and these two keys are available for each entry.

```py
for log in logs:
   buff = log.split()
   if buff[0] not in outlist.keys():
      outlist[buff[0]] = {}

   if buff[2] == 'sign-in':
      outlist[buff[0]].update({'sign-in':buff[1]})
   elif buff[2] == 'sign-out':
      # Here, make sure that "sign-in" goes first
      if "sign-in" not in outlist[buff[0]]:
          outlist[buff[0]]["sign-in"] = None
      outlist[buff[0]]['sign-out']=buff[1]

print(outlist)
>> {'12': {'sign-in': '10', 'sign-out': '150'},
 '30': {'sign-in': '90', 'sign-out': '120'}}
```

However, if both keys won't always be there, this solution would contain `None` entries. For example:

```py
logs = ["12 150 sign-out","30 90 sign-in","30 120 sign-out"

# For above case, we would have outlist as
print(outlist)

>> {'12': {'sign-in': None, 'sign-out': '150'},
 '30': {'sign-in': '90', 'sign-out': '120'}}
```

Note however, that even though above solution is one pass, time complexity would still be `O(2N)` because now in each loop, you are doing more work. Though `O(2N)` and `O(N)` are same thing.

Otherwise, it doesn't seem to be possible to do it in one pass without looking ahead.

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding ordering. So basically, we cant order it in a single pass. We need to do a separate sort and the time order would become 2N. This is helpful to know.

Comment: Note that the time complexity would not be `O(2N)` but `O(2N*log(k))` where `k` is the number of keys in each dictionary under `outlist`. But if there are only two keys possible i.e. `sign-in` and `sign-out`, it is possible to do it in one pass. I will modify the solution to incorporate that.

Comment: @ATK you don't actually need to modify your original code to achieve the linear time complexity.

Comment: Yes, I modified that to achieve it in single pass